# Are there any academic articles that deal directly with the psychology / sociology of Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, research, academic

Are there any academic articles that deal directly with the psychology / sociology of Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange?

I was trying to google this to see if there's any academic talk, but I didn't really see anything. This could certainly be due to my googling skills. I'm looking specifically for Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange and not general social networking or Q & A. I've seen *[Academic studies and Stack Overflow community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188399/academic-studies-and-stack-overflow-community)*, but I'm not really looking for a software engineering perspective (and I don't think they've published anything).

EDIT - just to be clear, I don't want software engineering / business articles  (which is what all the articles I have seen are) but psychology / sociology type.

Comment: Did you read [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/academic-papers-using-stack-overflow-data/) already? Lots of links in there.

Comment: I'd see some of those but not that list. I was looking for less of a software engineering perspective and more psychology / sociology.

Comment: Don't think there is, to be honest.

Comment: thx; thx for list too.

Comment: Another interesting reading for you, with links to more: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56469/what-aspects-of-psychology-does-stack-overflow-take-advantage-of

Comment: thx for comment @AlienArrays I agree with what you're saying (and was a bit the reason I asked the question). The nerds have it first - woudl bre intersting to have a corporate focused SE. I also find it ineresting the explicit decisions to not do (following other users, user-to-user messaging).