# Where can I ask Stackoverflow users to participate in an academic study?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, research, stack-overflow-developer-survey

I'm writing my Master's thesis in  Economics and would like to investigate the link between Stackoverflow and salary improvements of its users compared to national averages (by role), as well as run some interesting regressions on the awesome data provided by StackExchange (thanks!!)

The only missing link is a way to measure salary **improvement**.

I tried contacting the StackExchange team to have a sample of the non-anonymized Developer Survey, but that was a no go (understandibly!).

My plan B would be a 3 question survey that would make the data more accurate and the process faster! Other solutions would be a bit more "dirty" and would require scraping public information and making estimates.

So after this preample, **my question is**: what is the best way, respecting site guidelines, to reach out to users and ask them to participate?

Comment: Placing an ad on Stack Overflow would do it... their minimum is $500.

Comment: You might find [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188399/academic-studies-and-stack-overflow-community) question helpful.

Comment: @Normal Human: Great idea, I'll contact the team and see if we can collaborate on the ad placement.

Comment: As a starting point re: placing an ad, see http://stackexchange.com/mediakit

Comment: Related [Academic studies and Stack Overflow community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188399)